# Margin footnotes not working in memoir with polyglossia + Hebrew

Tags: memoir, polyglossia, marginnote

I am working on typesetting my master's thesis, using XeLaTeX and `memoir`.  Everything has been going quite well, until I wanted to add a small message in Hebrew in my preface.  I am using the `polyglossia` package and although the little bit of Hebrew that I wanted came out just fine, it undid the `\footnotesinmargin` setting from `memoir`.  If necessary I can do just fine without the Hebrew text, as long as `polyglossia` doesn't interfere with my footnotes while using English and French (which it doesn't seem to do).  But I would still very much like to understand what causes this incompatibility. This relatively minimal example is part of my setup, with my margin and footnote commands.  If I comment out `\setotherlanguage{hebrew}` everything is fine, but if I don't then the footnotes are sent to the bottom of the page.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum}


%% MISE EN PAGE %%

% Géométrie de la page
\settypeblocksize{54.3163pc}{*}{0.5}
\setbinding{1pc}
\setlrmargins{4.312pc}{*}{*}
\setulmargins{6.1pc}{*}{*}
\setheadfoot{0pt}{2.5\onelineskip}
\setmarginnotes{2pc}{12pc}{2\onelineskip}
\checkandfixthelayout

% Notes de bas de page
\footnotesinmargin
\footmarkstyle{#1~}
\setlength{\footmarkwidth}{-1sp}
\setlength{\footmarksep}{0pt}
\setlength{\footparindent}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\foottextfont}{\scriptsize\raggedright}

%% LANGUES %%

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[variant=usmax]{english}
\setotherlanguage{french}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test Chapter}

\lipsum[1]

And now some dummy text\footnote{Test footnote that should show up in the margin.} so that I can have a footnote.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you need to load polyglossia definitions for Hebrew just for that one passage?

Comment: In that case yes, that's the only section I needed it for.  I wound up just compiling a separate standalone document in Hebrew and including it as a graphic.  A very inelegant solution I'm afraid...